# Iterating through map of objects in terraform with route 53 records

Tags: for-loop, foreach, terraform, amazon-route53

I am trying to figure out how to read from additional values in Terraform using for / for_each using Terraform 0.12.26

**dns.tfvars**

```
mx = {
  "mywebsite.org." = {
    ttl = "3600"
    records = [
      "home.mywebsite.org.",
      "faq.mywebsite.org."
    ]
  }
  "myotherwebsite.org." = {
    ttl = "3600"
    records = [
      "home.myotherwebsite.org."
    ]
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "mx" {
  type = map(object({
    ttl     = string
    records = set(string)
  }))
}
```

**mx.tf**

```
locals {
  mx_records = flatten([
    for mx_key, mx in var.mx : [
      for record in mx.records : {
        mx_key = mx_key
        record = record
        ttl    = mx.ttl
    }]
  ])
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {
  for_each = { for mx in local.mx_records : mx.mx_key => mx... }
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name     = each.key
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = each.value.ttl

  records = [
    each.value.record
  ]
}
```

In mx.tf, I can comment out the second value, faq.mywebsite.org, and the code works perfectly. I cannot figure out how to set up my for loop and for each statements to get it to "loop" through the second value. The first error I had received stated below:

```
Error: Duplicate object key

  on mx.tf line 13, in resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records":
  13:   for_each = { for mx in local.mx_records : mx.mx_key => mx }
    |----------------
    | mx.mx_key is "mywebsite.org."

Two different items produced the key "mywebsite.org." in this 'for'
expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value
expression to enable grouping by key.
```

To my understanding, I do not have two duplicate values helping to form the key so I should not have to use the ellipsis, but I tried using the ellipsis anyway to see if it would apply properly. After adding on the ellipsis after the value expression, I got this error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on mx.tf line 20, in resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records":
  20:     each.value.record
    |----------------
    | each.value is tuple with 2 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Any advice on this issue would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create resource record set [name='mywebsiteorg.', type='MX'] but it already exists]
    status code: 400, request id: dadd6490-efac-47ac-be5d-ab8dad0f4a6c
```

It's trying to create the record, but it already created because of the first record in the list.

Comment: Hi. Its a side note. I've noticed that you have a lot of questions with answers, but you haven't accepted any of them. Its fine if all of them weren't helpful (then a comment would be warranted), but if they were correct, they should be accepted. This not only shows to others that the question was answered, but people may simply stop answering to your questions. Non-accepted answers also appear [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terraform?tab=Unanswered) which adds to confusion if the answers are actually correct, solve the issue, but are not-accepted.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the advice. I will go through old questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could just construct a map of your objects with key being the index of `mx_records` list (note the `idx` being the index):

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {

  for_each = { for idx, mx in local.mx_records : idx => mx }

  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id

  name     = each.value.mx_key
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = each.value.ttl

  records = [
    each.value.record
  ]
}
```

The above for_each expressions changes your `local.mx_records` from list(objects) to map(objects), where the map key is `idx`, and the value is the original object.

Update:

I verified in Route53 and you can't duplicate codes. Thus may try using orginal `mx` variable:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {

  for_each = { for idx, mx in var.mx : idx => mx }

  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id

  name     = each.key
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = each.value.ttl

  records = each.value.records
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin. Thank you for the advice. This helps a lot but I just had one last thing. For the record that I am trying to loop through I am getting an error: Error: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: [Tried to create resource record set [name='mywebsite.org.', type='MX'] but it already exists]
        status code: 400, request id: dadd6490-efac-47ac-be5d-ab8dad0f4a6c

Comment: @DaveMichaels No problem. Do you have already such records created in Route53? maybe there were created manually, outside of terraform? Sadly I can't verify that behavior, as I don't  have route53 records to test with at the moment.

Comment: I think what is happening is Terraform creates the first record with the first value, and then when it's time to apply the second value it realizes this record was already created and then generates that error.

Comment: @DaveMichaels yes. `mywebsite.org.` will appear twice, and you can't duplicate code as in the updated answer. Then maybe better to stick with the original mx record, instead of changing it to three records in your `locals`.

Comment: @DaveMichaels I added other example, but I think you will need  somewhere [route53_zone](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_zone). So you would have two zones, one for `mywebsite.org.` and the other for `myotherwebsite.org.`, Then you can create the records in their zones. Basically you need to re-think your design from what I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, I need to create the record in one zone and be able to have these additional values attached to this record. Terraform at apply time shows the expected result, but then during execution errors out stating the record already exists since Terraform is trying to create the record an additional time. I wonder if there's a work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, if you want to avoid flatten function and for loop local variable, you can access the object in the map as:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "mx_records" {
  for_each = var.mx
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id
  name     = each.key
  type     = "MX"
  ttl      = each.value["ttl"]
  records = each.value["records"]
}
```